# How to get cron job information through k8s selector

Tags: kubernetes, cron

I'm trying to get information for a cron job so I can grab the current release of service.

So when I run `kubectl get pods` I get:

```
NAME                                      READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
cron-backfill-1573451940-jlwwj            0/1     Completed   0          33h
test-pod-66df8ccd5f-jvmkp                 1/1     Running     0          16h
```

When I run `kubectl get pods --selector=job-name=cron-backfill` I get:

```
No resources found in test namespace.
```

But when I run `kubectl get pods --selector=app=test-pod` I get:

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test-pod-66df8ccd5f-jvmkp          1/1     Running   0          16h
```

which is what I want. I figured since the first pod is a cron job there must be some other command used to check for those, but no luck.

I tried looking through the k8s docs here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/ but can't find something that seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to

```
kubectl describe pods cron-backfill-1573451940-jlwwj
```

And then you can see the `Labels:` part

EX:

```
Labels:             app=<app-name>
                    controller-uid=<xxxxxxxxxx>
                    job-name=cron-backfill-1573451940-jlwwj 
                    release=<release-name>
```

Final you can use following command to get your pods:

```
kubectl get pods --selector=job-name=cron-backfill-1573451940-jlwwj
```

Hope this may help you, Guy!